# How to write the Hessian

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Do you know if there is any command to write "Hess f"? What is the standard? Should I just write it as text?

Thank you!

Comment: You made an error in your command, @Bernard, it should be `\DeclareMathOperator{\hess}{Hess}`. You forgot a `{` again!

Comment: Anyway, I'll remove my comment, since there's an answer now. Thanks for being watchful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will work nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hessian}{Hess}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  (\Hessian f)_{ij} &\equiv \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j} } \\
  \Hessian\left( \frac{x^{2}}{y} \right) &= 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{y} & - \frac{2x}{y^{2}} \\
    -\frac{2x}{y^{2}} & \frac{2x^{2}}{y^{3}}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]